# Flexbox parent shrinks smaller than children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I prevent this flex parent from shrinking to smaller than the height of the children? The grey container is the flex parent, the white boxes are the children.

[image: Flex children extend outside parent]

```
grey box
  display flex

white boxes
  display block
  height 200px
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered the problem; it was caused by a css reset with the rule:

```
body, html { height: 100%; }
```

The problem disappeared once I changed this to:

```
body { height:auto; min-height:100%; }
html { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: If this doesn't solve the problem, check with `flex-shrink: 0;`. That solved my problem

Comment: this is so weird, no way it makes sense. Body height is affecting flexbox everywhere inside???

Comment: My site was a fullscreen/no-scroll layout, so this was the fix for me. In hindsight... This probably applies to nobody else, and isn't a very useful answer. I recommend asking your own question if you're still having issues.

Comment: This got me to a step closer to finding a solution, but the problem is that I do want my body to be 100% so I can flex the items in there and vertically center them...

Answer (score 2):

I found what may be the real answer. This solved it for me:

At least one of the children of a "display: flex" parent MUST have the attribute "flex: [some number]". In my scenario, once I set flex to 1 for my child, suddenly the other child stopped its odd shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial answer: add `min-height: 200px` on the grey box (the container).

(Though: if you're not providing a height for the grey box (the flex container), it should *already* auto-size to fit its children's height -- though that depends on the context, e.g. if the flex container's parent is another flex container. Anyway, you'll probably have to provide more specifics & a working testcase, if you want a more appropriate answer. :))